# Sweet alert no works with cancel button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bind, sweetalert

I'm using the sweet alert library and I have a problem with the cancel button. This is my code for the sweet alert:

```
sweetAlert({
        title: title,
        text: text + ' ' + courseList,
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: confirmButtonText,
        cancelButtonText: "Continue with purchase",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        closeOnCancel: false,
        html: true
    },
    function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            angular.forEach(repeatedCourses, function(repeatedCourse) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    this.removeCoursePurchase(repeatedCourse);
                }.bind(this));
            }.bind(this));
            $rootScope.$broadcast('uncheckCheckboxes');
            swal("Deleted!", "Your purchase has been refreshed.", "success");
        } else {
            swal("Cancelled", "Your imaginary file is safe :)", "error");
        }
    }.bind(this));
```

When the user click on the confirm button, works fine, but If the cancel button is clicked doesn't do anything, it doesn't appear the "Cancelled" box and I don't know why!

Comment: @RGraham the abbrevation for the function sweetAlert

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint on the `else` statement? Does it get hit?

Comment: Yes, and it doesn't enter inside the `function(isConfirm){}` when the user click on the cancel button, but it does when click on accept. @RGraham

Comment: @Crisiiii Have you solved it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the .bind(this) attached to the callback function and it will work.

Comment: True, but that would break other functionality. What actual solution would make sure both work?

Comment: Instead of bind to this, use var _self = this; instead